# Vue - Create New Project failing

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I'm new to Vue and have been trying to follow tutorial instructions, but I keep getting the same problem when I try to create a new project.

Can anyone please help me understand what these errors mean and how to fix them?

```
Ready on http://localhost:8000
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bit703/module6/themes/philter2/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/16.1.0/bin/node /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bit703/module6/themes/philter2/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o ../src/libsass/src/base64vlq.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o ../src/libsass/src/bind.cpp
npm ERR!   cc '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o ../src/libsass/src/check_nesting.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o ../src/libsass/src/color_maps.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o ../src/libsass/src/constants.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o ../src/libsass/src/context.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o ../src/libsass/src/cssize.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o ../src/libsass/src/emitter.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o ../src/libsass/src/environment.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/include/node -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/src -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-gyp/16.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/error_handling.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/error_handling.o ../src/libsass/src/error_handling.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/chrisgill/.node-


    at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-ui/apollo-server/connectors/projects.js:354:5
    at async Object.wrap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-ui/apollo-server/connectors/progress.js:39:14) {
  code: 1,
  stdout: '✨  Creating project in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bit703/module6/themes/philter2.\n'
```

Comment: You need to share more information. How do you try to create a new project? What is the command you use? Do you use "vue cli" or your own webpack configuration etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused by selecting "Sass/SCSS (with node-sass)" as the CSS pre-processor.
I don't know why it's a problem, but choosing "Sass/SCSS (with dart-sass)" seems to work, I'm using a Mac.